Efficient constructions of NP-complete problem instances
Is it possible to have a polynomial-time algorithm(possibly randomized) that constructs instances of an NP-complete problem that are hard to solve?
In particular, I have the following thoughts.
I am going to try to construct instances of $\textrm{3-COLORING}$, i.e. the language consisting of all graphs $G$ for which there exists a 3-coloring, i.e. a coloring of the vertices with say red, blue, and green such that no 2 adjacent vertices are the same color.
I can construct instances as follows:

Decompose $V = R\bigsqcup G \bigsqcup B$. These will be the sets of vertices that are colored red, green and blue respectively.
For each pair of vertices $u, v$ in different color sets, I add $e = (u, v)$ to the graph with some fixed probability $p$.

My question is, does the specific class of instances generated by such an algorithm admit some polynomial-time solution(possibly randomized)?

Something that's relevant to the question in your title and your first sentence: if you have any NP-complete problem $C$, then you can generate a hard instance by generating a hard instance of any problem in NP, since by the definition of NP-completeness, you can transform this to an instance of $C$ that's at least as hard, in polynomial time. So, for example, you can generate a hard SAT instance or a hard factorisation problem. How practical this is depends a bit on what $P$ is exactly.
